# Tumblr like-button affecting other variables?

Tags: javascript, tumblr

My notes on Tumblr are not working correctly, as you can see here: http://herrhansen.tumblr.com/post/19630628091 (bottom of page)

I believe that the variable {PostNotes} usually puts the like-notes and the reblog-notes in a list. But my notes are somehow divided, as if only my 'like-notes' are affected by the CSS and the 'reblog-notes' are displayed very strange.

I am guessing that the JavaScript, which i am using for a tumblr like-button (copied from http://like-button.tumblr.com/) is messing with my notes.

Could that be possible?

here is the javascript for the like-button:

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<iframe id="my-like-frame"             style="display:none;"></iframe>' );
document.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {
var myLike = event.target;
if( myLike.className.indexOf( 'my-like' ) > -1 ) {
    var frame = document.getElementById( 'my-like-frame' ),
        liked = ( myLike.className == 'my-liked' ),
        command = liked ? 'unlike' : 'like',
        reblog = myLike.getAttribute( 'data-reblog' ),
        id = myLike.getAttribute( 'data-id' ),
        oauth = reblog.slice( -8 );
    frame.src = 'http://www.tumblr.com/' + command + '/' + oauth + '?id=' + id;
    liked ? myLike.className = 'my-like' : myLike.className = 'my-liked';
};
}, false );
};
</script>
```

I've tried putting the variable into a list, but the list's positioning only works on the like-notes.

Even when the code is as simple as this (without tags) :

```
 {block:PostNotes} 

                    {PostNotes}

                        {/block:PostNotes}
```

the notes turn out strange.

Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with javascript. Is it possibly causing the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code is added on load but triggered only on the click of the like button, so since I see the bad formatting on every page load I have to conclude that this JavaScript is not the issue.

I would look to CSS and HTML formatting issues. Interestingly, [it does not appear to be the HTML for the list itself](http://jsfiddle.net/hvZxA/1/).

EDIT: It's this "reblog" class attribute, which is only present on your broken elements. Go into Firebug or Dev Tools and remove it and you'll see formatting is restored.

```
div .reblog {
position: relative;
left: 90%;
top: -9px;
height: 18px;
display: inline-block;
width: 17px;
z-index: 1;
}
```